# Are these parts for heavy duty shelves?

Tags: shelves

The former owner left these in our garage.
I am now cleaning up the garage and I found them again
Not sure what they are

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking cubicle connectors, but it really doesn't matter if all you have it the brackets - they are (now, at least) right angle brackets for whatever use you have for them - feel free to drill more holes as needed.

Comment: For hanging a dryer on the wall.

Comment: don't know about that the former owner had the dryer on the floor. He was an auto mechanic by trade ...maybe that gives you guys a clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think they can be general purpose use, not just for shelving, but anything that needs a right angle bracket.

The slotted holes might made for something that needed/used adjustment, so probably not made for shelving as primary use.

Comment: Maybe a stair tread cleat/bracket?

Comment: the second picture shows that on that side (bottom) there is some soft sponge or something meant to absorb shocks and vibrations or to protect the surface it gets in touch with when screwed in position